# Are pip and python consistent? Seems like the answer is no. Can someone help me decrypt the documentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

So i'm trying to implement stripe on a Django app and i'm having issues.

I installed Stripe using pip3 -install stripe and it downloaded. However when I run the server it says

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stripe'

So looking around and on this I think I found some sort of an answer.
https://nomodulenamed.com/a/I-have-installed-the-package-using-pip#fail-to-install

Are pip and python consistent?
Seems like the answer is no.

pip3 -V  returned pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

and

python3 -V returned Python 3.8.2

It seems that the easy fix is using python3 -m pip3 -V but that returns No module named pip3

and

python3 -m pip -V returns pip 20.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

but pip -V returns zsh: command not found: pip

which leaves me quite confused

more over i'm suppose to do # install your package

> `python -m pip <your-package-name>`

so what goes in the place of

> `<your-package-name>`

and I'm I suppose to use pip of pip3 since I use pip3 to install thing.

Comment: `pip` is independent of any particular Python interpreter, but may have a shebang that specifies a version with which to execute it that differs from the interpreter found via your `PATH` variable.

Comment: You appear to have at least two different Python installations on your machine, `/usr/local/lib/python3.7` and (perhaps) `/usr/lib/python3.8`. Your `pip3` executable appears to use `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` (or similar) as its shebang, and the 3.7 installation has the `pip` module installed, while the Python 3.8 installation does not.

Comment: sorry a piece of my question was not visible due to the <>. How do I manage to solve or go around that ?

Comment: I believe I have 3 different versions of python installed. that included the default python 2.7 that came with the computer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you can have more than one Python2 installation and more than one Python3 installation available on your machine, your question is better answered by understanding virtual environments.
**It is precisely the reason why virtual environments exist!**
when you create a python3 virtual environment there is no need to call pip3 as it is the default pip.
start by creating your virtual env (Assuming you have virtualenv installed ... if not install it on linux ubuntu by calling

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
sudo apt-get install python3-pip

python3 -m venv env
source bin/env/activate

pip install <yourpackage>
```

but I believe you are on macOS since you are getting  zsh error,
fix your installation by using homebrew

```
brew install python3
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 <path-to your-project>
source <path-to your-project>/bin/activate
```

Comment: You don't need `virtualenv` to use the `venv` module.